# Type: String suivre le lien (ctrl + clic) The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.dartargument_type_not_assignable)

Tags: flutter, dart, http

I have a problem with my codes. I look for solution this:

```
*class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  
  Future<List> getData() async {
    final response= await http.get("http://10.0.2.2/mon_stock/getdata.php");
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }*
```

Can you help me here

Comment: Use Uri.parse("http>//...")

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data